# find the first occurrence of non-alphanumeric character in a string

Tags: php, indexof, strpos, non-alphanumeric

I know that i could use `strpos` to find the first occurrence of a string. But is it possible to find the first occurrence of a character that is not an alphabetic character or number.

For example:

`strpos2('hello world') => 5`

`strpos2('hi!you') => 2`

Comment: `strpos` worked for all character. you can use `strpos('hello world',' ')` and `strpos('hi!you','!')`.

Comment: @MohammadHamedani I am not asking for a specific character. I want to find the first occurrence of a non-alphabetic character (any character). Not to find the first space or !.

Comment: preg_split with`[^\w]` and take strlen of the first chunk. If you don't want `_` write a stronger condition

Comment: @splash58 yes. I think `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/` is more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `preg_match`

```
$string = "hi!you";
preg_match('/[\W]+/', $string, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($match);
```

Here $match will return position of first matching non alphabetic character

Comment: thanks. I think some changes will improve it: `if(preg_match("/[\W]+/", $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        $index = $matches[0][1];
    }`

Comment: Ya its up-to you which information you have to extract from it

Comment: Well, I asked for the first occurrence.

Comment: Yes go for it.. :)